# Pageant - Win 10 - Cannot load keys on startup

Tags: pageant

If I run pageant and add keys, there is no problem. The key gets loaded without issues.

If I create a shortcut to run pageant and load the keys at the same time, like so:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pageant.exe" H:\keys\key.ppk
```

Then I get the error:

```
Couldn't load this key (unable to open file)
```

Happens if the shortcut is run as admin or not.

What could be causing this?

H: is a network drive

Comment: And if you run the same command in `cmd.exe` console window?

Comment: And what does `dir C:\keys\key.ppk` show?

Comment: Thank you, Martin, it seems obvious now but that helped me narrow down the problem :)

Answer (score 4):

In your shortcut, try to put the keys directory in the "Start in" option, like this:

```
Target: "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pageant.exe" key1.ppk key2.ppk key3.ppk etc.

Start in: "C:\keys"
```

See if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this is actually pretty embarrassing, but the problem was that the real path to my keys had spaces in it, and so I was simply missing quotes in the shortcut, like so:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pageant.exe" "H:\actual path to keys\key.ppk"
```